# JPA criteria API query subclass property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, criteria, criteria-api

I want to execute a query matching a specific subclass property, so I'm trying to use `treat()`.

In this example I want:

*all subjects with name starting with 'a',

or all subjects, which are persons, with last name starting with 'a'*

```
private List<Subject> q1()
{
    CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Subject> q = b.createQuery(Subject.class);
    Root<Subject> r = q.from(Subject.class);
    q.select(r);
    q.distinct(true);
    q.where(
        b.or(
            b.like(r.get(Subject_.name), "a%"),
            b.like(b.treat(r, Person.class).get(Person_.lastName), "a%")));

    return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
}
```

Obviously, `Person` extends `Subject`, `Subject` is abstract, inheritance is `SINGLE_TABLE`, <del>and `Subject` has `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` for other reasons</del> (non influent).

But the generated SQL is this:

```
select distinct subject0_.ID as ID2_71_, subject0_.CODE as CODE3_71_, ...
from SUBJECT subject0_ 
where subject0_.DTYPE='Person' and (subject0_.name like 'a%' or subject0_.lastName like 'a%')
```

while I'm expecting:

```
select distinct subject0_.ID as ID2_71_, subject0_.CODE as CODE3_71_, ...
from SUBJECT subject0_ 
where subject0_.name like 'a%' or (subject0_.DTYPE='Person' and subject0_.lastName like 'a%')
```

**Is there a way to produce the expected query using criteria builder?**

Note that

- using another *Root* - `q.from(Person.class)`
- using subqueries - `q.subquery(Person.class)`
- moving *lastName* field up to *Subject*
- using Native Queries
- using Entity Graphs

**are not acceptable**.

I'm interested in something which can be declared and used directly in *WHERE* clause (**produced only from *CriteriaBuilder* and/or the single *Root***, just like the `treat()` clause), if it does exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is, with Hibernate and in this specific scenario, very simple:

```
private List<Subject> q1()
{
    CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Subject> q = b.createQuery(Subject.class);
    Root<Subject> r = q.from(Subject.class);
    q.select(r);
    q.distinct(true);
    q.where(
        b.or(
            b.like(r.get(Subject_.name), "a%"),
            b.and(
                b.equal(r.type(), Person.class),
                b.like(((Root<Person>) (Root<?>) r).get(Person_.lastName), "a%"))));

    return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
}
```

Note the **double cast**, which avoids compilation error, and allows to perform the query clause on the same table. This generates:

```
select distinct subject0_.ID as ID2_71_, subject0_.CODE as CODE3_71_, ...
from SUBJECT subject0_ 
where subject0_.DTYPE in ('Office', 'Team', 'Role', 'Person', ...) 
    and (subject0_.name like 'a%' 
        or subject0_.DTYPE='Person' and (subject0_.lastName like 'a%'))
```

There's no need to change the model or anything else.

Comment: I'm getting the usual error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [inheritedTags] on this ManagedType [...]`. What am I doing wrong? (My subclass is abstract) I really need the answer please help!

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Your expecting sql - while it can be genereated with pure jpa crtieria api - it won't work and will cast an exception becasue you (hibernate) cannot Instantiate the abstract class subject.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate
>   abstract class or interface:

If the class is not abstract it works. like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder b = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Contact> q;
q = b.createQuery(Contact.class);
Root r = q.from(Contact.class);

   q.select(r);
   q.distinct(true);
q.where(
        b.or(
                b.like(r.get(Contact_.name),"t%"),
                b.and(
                        b.equal(r.get(Contact_.contact_type),"customer"),
                        b.like(r.get(Customer_.lastName),"t%")
                )
        )
);

return getEntityManager().createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

(My Customer is your person, and my subject class is the contact class)

---

Accessing the discriminator column as a readonly might be a working workaround for you.
if discriminator_column is contact_type do:

```
@Column(name = "contact_type",insertable = false,updatable = false)
@XmlTransient
private String contact_type;
```

Then Contact being an abstract class with customer as subclass the following :

```
CriteriaBuilder b = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Contact> q = b.createQuery(Contact.class);
           Root<Contact>  r = q.from(Contact.class);
           q.distinct(true);

           q.where(
                b.or(
                        b.like(r.get(Contact_.name), "t%"),
                        b.and(
                                b.equal(r.get(Customer_.contact_type), "customer"),
                                b.like(r.get(Customer_.name), "%t")
                        )
                )
                );
           return getEntityManager().createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

Produces

```
select

distinct contact0_.id as id2_1_,
    contact0_.contact_type as contact_1_1_,
    contact0_.name as name3_1_ 
from
    Contact contact0_ 
where
    contact0_.name like ? 
    or contact0_.contact_type=? 
    and (
        contact0_.name like ?
    )
```

Comment: You are accessing *Customer_.name*, which is the same as *Contact_.name*. it will not work if you use a property defined on *Customer* and results in compilation error *The method get(SingularAttribute<? super Contact,Y>) in the type Path<Contact> is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<Customer,String>)*

Comment: See my update, if you ommit the type of root that problem does not occur.

Comment: You're messing with something that has little to do with metamodel query translation... but your update pointed me in the right direction. Though not  worth the bounty or acceptance, still it's worth a couple of +1. Thanks.