# JPA criteria API query subclass property along with superclass properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, single-table-inheritance, criteriaquery

This is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="library_entities", schema="jamschema")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public abstract class Entity {
    private UUID id;
    private String title;
    private String tags;
    ...
}

@Entity
public abstract class Artwork extends Entity {
    private String inheritedTags;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class Album extends Entity {
    private Set<Track> tracks;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("T")
public class Track extends Entity {
    private Album album;
    ...
}
```

I need to search for entities using their base class attributes (e.g. title, tags, etc.) AND `Artwork`'s attributes (e.g. inheritedTags) if they exist.
In other words I need a query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM Entity entities WHERE entities.title like '...' OR entities.tags like 
'...'OR (entities.type in ('A', 'T') AND (entities.inheritedTags like '...' OR 
entities.title like '...' OR entities.tags like '...'))
```

`criteriaBuilder.treat()` is not the solution because it only queries the subclass (not the superclass).
And according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391498/5612892) the following must be a workaround:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Entity> query = 
builder.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);
query.select(root);
    query.where(
        builder.or(
            builder.like(root.get("title"), "%a"),
            builder.like(root.get("tags"), "%a"),
            builder.and(
                builder.equal(root.type(), Artwork.class),
                builder.like(
                    ((Root<Artwork>) (Root<?>) root).get("inheritedTags"), "%a")
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

But it's not and I still get the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [inheritedTags] on this ManagedType [com...Entity]`

```
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:148)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:119)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:117)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:44)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractFromImpl.locateAttributeInternal(AbstractFromImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:204)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:177)
at com.jamapplicationserver.AppMain.lambda$main$1(AppMain.java:99)
at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:134)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1584)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

It seems like Hibernate looks for the attribute in the super class and since the attribute (`inheritedTags`) is not present on the super class, it throws the exception.
How can I resolve this without changing the model?

Comment: If you do Root<Entity> root = query.from(Artwork.class) <-- Doesn't that allow you to access both Artwork properties plus its parent (inheritedTags) attributes.

Comment: This would return Artwork objects only.@SusanMustafa